# sql : copying into a table in chunks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My task is I need to create index on a large table in SQL Server (~370G). The plan is to

1. create a new table with the same columns and
2. create a clustered index in the new table on three columns
3. copy in small chunks (grouped by the three columns) the original data into the new table.

I can do 1) and 2) in SQL with the following script:

```
SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO js_sample_indexed
FROM dbo.js_sample

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX domain_event_platform_idx 
ON dbo.js_sample_indexed (domain ASC, event_type ASC, platform ASC)  
GO
```

But I am stuck in the third step. Presumably there are thousands of values in the index, for example, an value might be ('Amazon', 'search', 'mobile').

So I might need to put a where statement in a for loop, while updating the condition for selection every time.

But I'm stuck at how to store and retrieve the values in each column (e.g. 'domain') using SQL.

Don't know whether I've phrased this question clearly, but any comments would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You say "thousands" - how many thousands? I would expect that a few thousand records would copy over in one step pretty easily and quickly.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the reply. The are 13 billion records, but I was referring there might be a few thousand distinct values in one column (e.g. 'domain')

Comment: Ahh, gotcha...Yeah, maybe 13 billion records wouldn't be a good thing to query all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with an answer after some reading and asking. Here is the code:

```
USE jumpshot_data
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.js_indexed

-- create a new table with existing structure
SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO dbo.js_full_indexed_1
FROM dbo.js_test

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX domain_event_platform_idx 
ON dbo.js_full_indexed_1 (domain ASC, event_type ASC, platform ASC)  
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX device_id_idx 
ON js_full_indexed_1 (device_id ASC);

-- using cursor to loop through meta-data table, and insert by chunk into the new table
DECLARE @event_type varchar(50)
DECLARE @platform varchar(50)
DECLARE @domain varchar(50)

DECLARE SelectionCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
SELECT * FROM dbo.js_index_info

OPEN SelectionCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM SelectionCursor into @event_type, @platform, @domain

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    -- operation at each row
    INSERT INTO dbo.js_full_indexed_1 
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.js_test
    WHERE event_type = @event_type AND domain = @domain AND platform = @platform

    -- loop condition
    FETCH NEXT FROM SelectionCursor into @event_type, @platform, @domain
END

CLOSE SelectionCursor
DEALLOCATE SelectionCursor
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that there is an identity field of some sort (a sequentially numbered field used as an index) on the table. For this example, I will call this field `ID`. If this is true, then a simple looping construct will do what you need.

```
DECLARE @MinID int, @MaxID int, @Step int = 10000  -- Move 10k records per loop

SELECT @MinID = MIN(ID), @MaxID = MAX(ID)
FROM MyTableToCopyFrom

While @@MinID <= @MaxID
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTableToCopyTo (Field1, Field2, Field3, Fieldx)
    SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
    FROM MyTableToCopyFrom 
    WHERE ID >= @MinId 
        AND ID < @MinId + @Step

    SET @MinID = @MinID + @Step
END
```

Comment: Thanks Laughing(?). This helps a lot. The case is we probably need to use three columns to specify a unique identifier (which will also be the index), but with the structure you kindly provided I can do something similar.

Comment: Hi @Laughing Vergil - I have searched a while myself but cannot solve it - do you happen to know if the conditions is on a categorical variable, say "event_type" and there are two types, how to do that?

Comment: That would make it hard to increment by values... but need to loop through a table of values...